# What type of joint is sternoclavicular joint?

Tags: human-anatomy

I know it is synovial and saddle shaped
It is complex as it involves a articular disc
But I want to know whether it is simple joint ( 2 bones ) or complex joint (more than 2 bones ) as it involves costoclavicular ligament which attaches to the costal cartilage of first rib?